# React Hooks, setTimeOut to set State to false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout, use-state

I have this scenario

```
const [showAlertLink, setShowAlertLink] = useState(false);

 const handleClick = () => {
     setShowAlertLink(true);
  };

<Button disableRipple onClick={handleClick}>

{!!showAlertLink &&  <Alert icon={<CheckIcon fontSize="inherit" />} onClose={() => setShowAlertLink(false)}>{t(`alert_link_copied`)}</Alert>}
```

At the moment if i click on the Icon i can close the Alert.
How can i make this alert closing automatically with a `SetTimeout` duration 2 seconds for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `useEffect`:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    let timeout
    if (showAlertLink) {
      timeout = setTimeout(() => setShowAlertLink(false), 2000);
    }
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [showAlertLink]);
```

It will trigger when `showAlertLink` value changes. If it is `true` it will set a timeout to set it to false in 2 seconds (`2000`).

Be careful that you always return the effect to clear the timeout (to ensure you don't get `tried to update state of an unmounted component`) error.

If you are using typescript, you can type `timeout` like so:

```js
let timeout: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>;
```